# WCF SOAP call doesn't sign message nor BinarySecurityToken

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap, signing

I'm trying for the last 4 days to write a soap client using .net and WCF to connect to a web service with specific security requirements.

The soap message needs to have the Timestamp, Message and BinarySecurityToken signed (not encrypted), the request is sent over a https connection, and uses soap 1.1.

Using soapui this proved possible, and the resulting raw message looks as follows:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://somewebservice.com/someoperation/v1" xmlns:v11="http://somewebservice.com/someoperation/types/v1">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:BinarySecurityToken 
            EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" 
            ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" 
            wsu:Id="X509-65E1C83C68B360A6311522317037930116">binarydata...</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>

      <ds:Signature Id="SIG-65E1C83C68B360A6311522317037936120" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">

        <ds:SignedInfo>
          <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="soapenv v1 v11" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
          </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
          <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>

          <ds:Reference URI="#TS-65E1C83C68B360A6311522317037928115">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsse soapenv v1 v11" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
              </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>/b2PmmLNJ+CdlMA0NGiD3SNMT5c=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>

          <ds:Reference URI="#id-65E1C83C68B360A6311522317037930119">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="v1 v11" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
              </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>+rIhQ2RiZNYKWU75lvUDsgGS4Ow=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>

          <ds:Reference URI="#X509-65E1C83C68B360A6311522317037930116">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
              </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>cn9f/Yn3Eer5h43znGZvSDfA8xE=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>

        <ds:SignatureValue>
          binarydata...
        </ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-65E1C83C68B360A6311522317037930117">
          <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-65E1C83C68B360A6311522317037930118">
            <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-65E1C83C68B360A6311522317037930116" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
          </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
      </ds:Signature>
      <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-65E1C83C68B360A6311522317037928115">
        <wsu:Created>2018-03-29T09:50:37Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2018-03-29T09:51:37Z</wsu:Expires>
      </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-65E1C83C68B360A6311522317037930119" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <v1:HasAnEboxRequest>
      <v11:QualityCode>ENTERPRISE</v11:QualityCode>
      <v11:EboxID>
        <v11:CompanyID>0474773230</v11:CompanyID>
      </v11:EboxID>
    </v1:HasAnEboxRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The key thing here is I think the three blocks between the SignedInfo tags.
(they reference Timestamp, Message and BinarySecurityToken)

I tried a lot of things, but I'm only able to end up with a message that just has the timestamp signed, as follows :

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
        <u:Created>2018-03-29T19:17:32.420Z</u:Created>
        <u:Expires>2018-03-29T19:22:32.420Z</u:Expires>
      </u:Timestamp>
      <o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-ae79fbee-ea5f-4ebb-b461-c141cd743bb7-1" 
            ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" 
            EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">binarydata...</o:BinarySecurityToken>
      <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">

        <SignedInfo>
          <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
          <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>

          <Reference URI="#_0">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <DigestValue>7WbZ1cY3CS4hKk7Pb6+wpFUQi8k=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>

        </SignedInfo>

        <SignatureValue>binarydata...</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
          <o:SecurityTokenReference>
            <o:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#uuid-ae79fbee-ea5f-4ebb-b461-c141cd743bb7-1"/>
          </o:SecurityTokenReference>
        </KeyInfo>
      </Signature>
    </o:Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <HasAnEboxRequest xmlns="http://somewebservice.com/someoperation/v1">
      <QualityCode xmlns="http://somewebservice.com/someoperation/types/v1">QUAL_EMP_NOSS</QualityCode>
      <EboxID xmlns="http://somewebservice.com/someoperation/types/v1">
        <CompanyID>0474773230</CompanyID>
      </EboxID>
    </HasAnEboxRequest>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Currently I have the following app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" />
    </startup>

  <system.serviceModel>

    <bindings>

      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="defaultBasicHttpBinding">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>

    </bindings>

    <client>
      <!-- specifies the endpoint to use when calling the service -->
      <endpoint address="https://someurl/someendpoint/v1"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration="defaultBasicHttpBinding"
          behaviorConfiguration="enableCallbackDebug"
          contract="ServiceReference1.EboxMessagePortType" name="MyBindingConfig">
          <identity>
            <dns value="aod:trusto:acc:ebox:publication"/>
          </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>      
        <behavior name="enableCallbackDebug">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate findValue="somecertsubjectname"
                storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                storeName="My"
                x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"
                />            
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

In code, I'm using a proxy class that was generated by a wsdl.

If someone has an idea on a solution that would be fantastic.

Also, I'm thinking maybe wcf isn't the best way to go in this situation, so any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some help for others,

I ended up not using wcf, instead using a template xml and signing the different parts using SignedXml (System.Security.Cryptography.Xml)